# Managing branches in Git

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project wherein we have three programmers(including myself) working on three different branches, 1 for each branch. Now, when we push our changes in our own branch that we're working on, should the other programmers pull the changes every time one of us pushes in our own branches? or it is okay to keep on working on our own branches until we reach the final state and just merge those three branches in the end?

Comment: Are your branches specific to each programmer? I recommend branches that is specific to the job/issue/feature at hand. Then after you merge those into `main`, delete the branch.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, I suggest avoiding parallel branches of development to continue for longer than necessary because it's much harder to understand and merge older code changes. Instead, have a reference branch (e.g. master) that serves as a basis for short-lived feature branches. As soon as a work unit is completed, merge it back to master. This will reduce the possibility of conflicts and even if they occur, it should be easier to resolve them as the relevant coding has been done recently.

That being said, there are many ways to organize branches around your development process. Without knowing more about your requirements, this answer can only be a starting point.

Comment: So every time we finished a work unit in our branches, we should merge it to master before proceeding to develop for new work units in the same branches?

Comment: I mentioned "short lived feature branches" because they tend to be easier to manage than long lived (e.g. developer-specific) branches. Those would have to keep up to date via merge or rebase which can get messy over time. It is possible to maintain them but it requires more effort and discipline.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

We keep the integrity of the main branch, no broken code, no half feature, treat main as the product users will see.

After that depends on how complex is your development environment, but developer branches used to develop a single feature before been merged to master are usually a bit messy, as you said, multiple people contributing with code. Every time you are sending code you risk having to solve conflict problems, those can be mitigated with well structured file structure.

[image]

[Check out GitFlow as an idea of how you can do things.](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html)